# How to see registers in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, register

What program is there in OSX that lets you see the status of registers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPU registers?  You do know they change constantly and are kept separately for every process (and thread), right?  `gdb` can show you registers (`info registers`).  If that's not it, I'm not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: In the Windows debug program typing r will display the status of all registers. I'm looking for something like that in OSX.

Comment: Then it's `info registers` as I said above.

Comment: It just says "The program has no registers now." Windows will always show the status of the registers.